# Join spatial point data to polygons in R

Tags: r, spatial-join, point-in-polygon

I am trying to perform a spatial join between point data and polygon data.

I have data that indicate the spatial coordinates of an event in my csv file A and have another file, shapefile B, that contains the boundaries of an area as polygons.

```
head(A)
  month   longitude latitude lsoa_code                   crime_type
1 2014-09 -1.550626 53.59740 E01007359        Anti-social behaviour
2 2014-09 -1.550626 53.59740 E01007359                 Public order
3 2014-09 -1.865236 53.93678 E01010646        Anti-social behaviour

head(B@data)
  code      name                                  altname
0 E05004934 Longfield, New Barn and Southfleet    <NA>
1 E05000448                   Lewisham Central    <NA>
2 E05003149                            Hawcoat    <NA>
```

I want to join the crime data A to my shapefile B to map the crime events that happen in my area A. Unfortunately I cannot perform an attribute join based `code` as the code in A refers to different units than the code in B.

I've read a number of tutorials and posts but could not find an answer. I tried:

```
joined = over(A, B)
```

and `overlay`, but did not accomplish what I wanted.

Is there a way to do this join directly or would an intermediate transformation from A to another format be needed?

Conceptually I want to select those points of A that fall into the `code` areas of B (similar to "join based on spatial location in ArcGIS").

Did someone have this issue and solved it?

Comment: Have you looked at `point.in.polygon()` in package `sp`?

Comment: @arvi1000 I have and will try this again. My thought about `point.in.polygon` was whether this would preserve the variables `month` and `crime_type` . Do you know about that?

Comment: I've tried a bit more with `point.in.poly` and have finally selected those points that fall into the relevant polygons. Thanks.

Comment: Then perhaps you should answer your own question with your solution. Remember, good answers are what this site is all about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point.in.poly function in the spatialEco package returns a SpatialPointsDataFrame object of the points that intersect an sp polygon object and optionally adds the polygon attributes.

First lets add the require packages and create some example data.

```
require(spatialEco)
require(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
sr1=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180114, 180553, 181127, 181477, 181294, 181007, 180409,
  180162, 180114), c(332349, 332057, 332342, 333250, 333558, 333676,
  332618, 332413, 332349)))),'1')
sr2=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180042, 180545, 180553, 180314, 179955, 179142, 179437,
  179524, 179979, 180042), c(332373, 332026, 331426, 330889, 330683,
  331133, 331623, 332152, 332357, 332373)))),'2')
sr3=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(179110, 179907, 180433, 180712, 180752, 180329, 179875,
  179668, 179572, 179269, 178879, 178600, 178544, 179046, 179110),
  c(331086, 330620, 330494, 330265, 330075, 330233, 330336, 330004,
  329783, 329665, 329720, 329933, 330478, 331062, 331086)))),'3')
sr4=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180304, 180403,179632,179420,180304),
  c(332791, 333204, 333635, 333058, 332791)))),'4')
sr=SpatialPolygons(list(sr1,sr2,sr3,sr4))
srdf=SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sr, data.frame(row.names=c('1','2','3','4'), PIDS=1:4, y=runif(4)))
```

Now, lets take a quick look at the data and plot it.

```
head(srdf@data)  # polygons
head(meuse@data) # points
plot(srdf)
points(meuse, pch=20)
```

Finally, we can intersect the points with the polygons. The results will be a SpatialPointsDataFrame object with, in this case, two extra attributes (PIDS, y) that were contained in the srdf polygon data.

```
  pts.poly <- point.in.poly(meuse, srdf)
    head(pts.poly@data)
```

If there is not a unique identification column in the polygon data you could easily add one.

```
srdf@data$poly.ids <- 1:nrow(srdf)
```

Once we have the points and polygons intersected, we can aggregate the points using the unique polygon ID's that were an attribute in the polygon data.

```
# Number of points in each polygon
tapply(pts.poly@data$lead, pts.poly@data$PIDS, FUN=length)

# Mean lead in each polygon
tapply(pts.poly@data$lead, pts.poly@data$PIDS, FUN=mean)
```

Comment: @ arvi1000, yes but sp::point.in.polygon produces a logical. The spatialEco:point.in.poly is a wrapper for over but returns an sp SpatialPointsDataFrame and shortcuts some steps in relating the polygon attributes, much like raster:intersect does for rgeos::gIntersect.

Comment: `sp::point.in.polygon` actually returns a numeric value (0=point is outside, 1=inside, 2=on edge, 3=on vertex). Could be the right thing for some circumstances. Thought it was helpful to note here, since this is a top google result for related terms

Answer (score 32):

`over()` from package `sp` can be a little confusing but works well. I'm assuming you've already made "A" spatial with `coordinates(A) <- ~longitude+latitude`:

```
# Overlay points and extract just the code column: 
a.data <- over(A, B[,"code"])
```

Instead of a point spatial object, this simply gives you a data frame, with the same no. rows as A, and a single variable "code" from each intersecting polygon from B.

```
# Add that data back to A:
A$bcode <- a.data$code
```

Comment: I have found `over()` to have issues with points at the vertices of the polygons, although I think this is the easiest solution I have found so far.

Comment: What issues have you had?

Comment: Exclusion. I need to explore it further. I'll pm you some data later today and we can look at it together if your interested. I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure there are some degeneracies in the algorithm that need to be taken care of, at least for my data.

Comment: Nevermind. It must be something with my data. This experimental set works fine. http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=m5sTjE4N&version=1

Comment: This is a much more straightforward approach than the accepted answer, and does not require installing additional packages other than rgdal.

Comment: @BryceFrank, actuall this is no longer the case. The spatialEco::point.in.polygon function now deals with some multipart geometries that sp::over does not handle correctly. There are argument options on exactly how results are returned from multipart overlays.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr like solution:

```r
library(spdplyr)

ukcounties <- geojsonio::geojson_read("data/Westminster_Parliamentary_Constituencies_December_2018_UK_BGC/uk_country.geojson",
                                      what = "sp")
pop <- read_excel("data/SAPE20DT7-mid-2017-parlicon-syoa-estimates-unformatted.xls",sheet = "data")
pop <- janitor::clean_names(pop)

ukcounties_pop <- ukcounties %>% inner_join(pop, by = c("pcon18nm" = "pcon11nm"))
```

The population data comes from: https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/parliamentaryconstituencymidyearpopulationestimates

I had to convert the shape files downloaded from to geoJson:
https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/westminster-parliamentary-constituencies-december-2018-uk-bgc/data?page=1

You can do so by:

```r
uk_constituencies <- readOGR("data/Westminster_Parliamentary_Constituencies_December_2018_UK_BGC/Westminster_Parliamentary_Constituencies_December_2018_UK_BGC.shp")
uk_constituencies # this is in tmerc format. we need to convert it to WGS84 required by geoJson format.

# First Convert to Longitude / Latitude with WGS84 Coordinate System
wgs84 = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'
uk_constituencies_trans <- spTransform(uk_constituencies, CRS(wgs84))

# Convert from Spatial Dataframe to GeoJSON
uk_constituencies_json <- geojson_json(uk_constituencies_trans)

# Save as GeoJSON file on the file system.
geojson_write(uk_constituencies_json, file = "data/Westminster_Parliamentary_Constituencies_December_2018_UK_BGC/uk_country.geojson")

#read back in:
ukcounties <- geojsonio::geojson_read("data/Westminster_Parliamentary_Constituencies_December_2018_UK_BGC/uk_country.geojson",
                                      what = "sp")
```