# extract data of polygon shape which intersect with point shape R and create data frame

Tags: r, polygon, point

I want to extract data of a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` `li` which intersect with the `SpatialPointsDataFrame` `p` R and then create a data frame with the coordinates and values of both objects. I tried

```
library(sf)

out <- st_intersection(p, li)
```

I get the error `Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPointsDataFrame', 'SpatialPoints', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')"`

Not all points intersect with the polygon shape.

How could I extract the data of a polygon shape based on a point shape and then create a data frame of the result?

Comment: You are trying to use a function intended for an "sf" class object, not "sp". There are many posts addressing this exact issue, please search the site!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join spatial point data to polygons in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r)

Comment: IMHO not a duplicate, as `over` doesn't seem to work with sf objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that in `point.in.poly()`, **sf** is running under the hood. In order to avoid being required to (install and) load yet another package, you might as well take the direct approach (**mapview** is only needed for the example data here):

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)

## for the sake of reproducibility, create 'Spatial' example data 
p = as(breweries, "Spatial")
li = as(franconia, "Spatial")

## convert it to 'sf'
p = st_as_sf(p)
li = st_as_sf(li)

## intersect polygons with points, keeping the information from both
pli = st_intersection(li, p)

## transform into a 'data.frame' by removing the geometry
st_geometry(pli) = NULL
head(pli)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer can indeed partly be found in the linked post [Join spatial point data to polygons in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I used the packages `spatialEco` and `sp` to "merge" the points with the polygons.

```
library(spatialEco)
library(sp)

pts.poly <- point.in.poly(p, li)
head(pts.poly@data)
```

Then I transformed the `SpatialPointsDataFrame` into a data frame by simply using

```
dat <- as.data.frame(pts.poly)
```