# Joinn shapefile attribute ID to point in R

Tags: r, spatial-join, point-in-polygon

I have a CSV file (about 1,000,000 georeferenced points) which contains point_id/latitude/longitude. I also have a shapefile which represents a grid cell_id/xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax. 
I am trying to join the grid attributes (specifically the cell_id) to the points from my CSV file. Basically I want to know in which cell the points fall.

So my output would look like that point_id/latitude/longitude/cell_id.

Here is the code I have been working on based on this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r) and that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370310/r-join-data-frame-coordinates-by-shapefile-regions-aka-join-attributes-by-loca):

```
library(sp)
points<-read.csv(file = "/Users/input.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
coordinates(points)<- ~longitude+latitude  
library(sf)
grid <- read_sf("/Users/grid.shp")
a.data <- raster::intersect(points,grid["cell_id",,,])
points$cell_id <- a.data$cell_id
write.csv(points, file = "/Users/points.csv")
```

However this does not gives me the cell_id but instead returns the point_id twice.

I have also tried using `over` but it yielded an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing and matching different object classes (sp and sf). The raster::intersect function may be able to deal with this but, it is a dangerous assumption and is not good practice. I would use the raster::shapefile function to read grid.shp (resulting in an sp object) and not attempt an index to limit to cell_id. Just let the function work and then deal with the resulting @data data.frame slot. You are trying to be too cleaver and it is causing problems. This really is a fairly simple point in polygon analysis.

First, create some example data (meuse point data) and r (polygon grid).

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

data(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y

r <- raster(extent(meuse), resolution = 100)
  r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
r <- as(r, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
  names(r@data) <- "cell_id"

plot(r)
  plot(meuse,col="red",pch=19,add=TRUE)
```

Now, we can use the `point.in.poly` function in the spatialEco package. This will intersect the point and polygon feature geometries and return the associated polygon attributes. By default the returned object will be a SpatialPointsDataFrame however, you can use `sp = FALSE` to result in an sf class object.

```
meuse_grid <- spatialEco::point.in.poly(meuse, r)
  names(meuse_grid)
  meuse_grid$cell_id
```

Comment: Surely if the grid is regular you can work out the raster  I,J for a point by arithmetic - subtract xmin, divide by cell width or similar...

Comment: @Spacedman, one would think but, I would not take it for granted that the cell_ids are uniform (they are in my example for simplicity sake). Also, one could have a grid with irregular "cell" sizes across the region. This would make it a non-systematic grid but, I have seen this type of data referred to as a grid.

Comment: The data function was just missing the closing. I do not see an error regarding plot margins, is this on your data on the example?

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I figures out the mistake I was doing on the code that I talked about in my previous comment. 
So I am able to replicate the first part of your code. However when I try to use the second part witch my data I get this message after running "pts_grid <- spatialEco::point.in.poly(pts, grid)" 
Error in st_geos_binop("intersects", x, y, sparse = sparse, prepared = prepared) : 
  st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

Comment: @MarcelCampion this error indicates that your data is missing a projection string or are in different projections. Check both data using: proj4string(x)

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Yes my point data was missing a projection string. Thank's a lot for your help on that. 
For those of you that want to assign a projection to points from a csv similar to the projection of a shapefile you can simply do that proj4string(meuse) <- proj4string(r) using Jeffrey's semantic.

Comment: Many spatial functions test for projection string equivalency and not actual projection space. As such, you could also set all of your data to NA using: proj4string(x) <- NA However, this assumes that your data overlaps in geographic space and are not in two different project spaces.