# Extracting polygon information from KML file into DataFrame

Tags: r, polygon, kml, extract, data-frame

I have KML file from downloaded https://data.gov.sg/dataset/electoral-boundary_2020. As you can see on the website, there are 31 sub-polygons and each of them has a label. I have loaded the KML on R.

I have a separate .csv data file with postal codes, latitude and longitude. I would like to extract the name of the polygons from the KML file to map to the .csv to give 4 columns:

```
postal_code latitude longitude Name
```

Where Name is the name the polygon if the postal_code fall within the polygon. How do I do this using R?

Here is a sample data

```r
library(rgdal)
library(spatialEco)
library(dplyr)

postal_code=c(117606, 640215, 600220, 628389, 118560, 267314, 129580, 268458)
latitude=c(1.283146, 1.348578, 1.340993, 1.303928, 1.277510, 1.321747, 1.315483, 1.322019)
longitude=c(103.7739, 103.7121, 103.7374, 103.6586, 103.7893, 103.7999, 103.7650, 103.7910)
df=cbind.data.frame(postal_code, latitude, longitude)

coordinates(df)<-~longitude+latitude

poly.sg=readOGR('Downloads/doc.kml', "ELD2020")
proj4string(poly.sg)
poly.sg=spTransform(poly.sg, CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))
```

I have tried to follow the steps in [Join spatial point data to polygons in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r)

```r
poly.sg2<-as(poly.sg, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
pts.poly<-point.in.poly(df, poly.sg2)
```

I received this error:

> Error in st_geos_binop("intersects", x, y, sparse = sparse, prepared =
> prepared,  : st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

Comment: Have you seen this article https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r?

Comment: @Taras Thank you for sharing the link. I have attempted to follow the steps in the link but encountered an error.

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: @MarcM it is in my question

Comment: Without seeing what is being imported from `readOGR` I can only speculate but, you do not need to coerce to an sp class as, it is already there. Meaning, the polg.sg2 object is not necessary. Besides, the `point.in.poly` function handles both sp and sf objects.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the CRS to the `df` object; if you print it you'll notice

```
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 8 
extent      : 103.6586, 103.7999, 1.27751, 1.348578  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA
```

That crs is `NA`;
so you have to set it:

```
library(raster) # for its Spatial*DataFrame print method
library(sp)
#...
coordinates(df)<-~longitude+latitude
sp::proj4string(df) = sp::CRS('+init=epsg:4326')
```

Then, when you print the `df` object again, you'll see:

```
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 8 
extent      : 103.6586, 103.7999, 1.27751, 1.348578  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +tow
```

Now your intersection should work

Comment: Is crs() in crs(df) from the package raster?

Comment: yes,  `raster::crs()`; I've edited the code; also, the object print in the code is from `raster` package

Comment: `spatialEco` imports `sp` and `raster` so both `proj4strings` and `crs` methods should be available